# Chrome Theme doesn't show

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 4.2.2 on a PowerPC Mac, OS 10.5.8.

In order to use Chrome Theme, I have installed Jeeeyul's Themes through the conventional Help--> 'Install New Software' process. It appears from 'Installed Software' (Eclipse's 'About…' box) that Jeeeyul's Themes is properly installed.

But in the Eclipse's Preferences matching option (General --> Appearance), Jeeeyul's Themes don't show: I just get 'Colors and Fonts' and 'Label Decorations'.

What is more, if I click and highlight the 'Appearance' line, a message is displayed, i.e. 'The currently displayed page contains invalid values.' Clicking it again brings up the expected 'Appearance' pane, but no value such as 'Jeeeyul's Themes — Chrome' shows in the associated drop-list.

Any clue ?

As to greg-449's question, here is the stack trace:

at org.eclipse.e4.ui.preferences.CSSEditorPreferences.updateInput(CSSEditorPreferences.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.preferences.CSSEditorPreferences.createContents(CSSEditorPreferences.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ViewsPreferencePage.createContents(ViewsPreferencePage.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1502)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$14.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3946)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.observerProc(Display.java:3536)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:4875)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDownSuper(Widget.java:1093)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDownSuper(Tree.java:2052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDown(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseDown(Control.java:2538)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDown(Tree.java:2007)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5495)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Widget.java:2102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Shell.java:2299)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Display.java:5004)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5153)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(NSApplication.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3618)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ShowPreferencePageHandler.execute(ShowPreferencePageHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa.CocoaUIHandler.runCommand(CocoaUIHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa.CocoaUIHandler.access$6(CocoaUIHandler.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa.CocoaUIHandler$8.widgetSelected(CocoaUIHandler.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1458)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3982)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3621)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Thanks

Comment: There is probably an error message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata about the 'invalid values'.

Comment: Hi, greg-449. Indeed, there is an error msg: **** !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2013-10-19 18:52:06.676
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException.*** I can only suspect there is one or more elements missing but, practically, it leads me to nowhere. Any idea ?

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: the plug-in package version is org.eclipse.jface_3.8.102.v20130123-162658.jar. If 3.8 stands for Eclipse 3.8, then it might not be compatible.

Comment: The jface plugin version does not match the Eclipse version - jface 3.8 is probably correct for Eclipse 4.2.2. Is there a stack trace in the log for the NullPointerException?

Comment: @greg-449 — Yes, there is, but it quite long… There is obviously not enough room to post it here. I'll try and edit the main question post.

Comment: MORE info: I am running J2SE 5.0 (from Apple). Could that be a lead?

Comment: @BriceCoustillas, I don't get it what has Chrome Theme got to do with this?

Comment: @Pacerier — I do not get it either… for it was FOUR years ago and I shifted long ago to NetBeans, which suits my needs much better than Eclipse did at the time I tried and initiated this thread.